# Creating Graphs Using a Degree Sequence

Tags: java, algorithm, language-agnostic, graph-theory

This is a part of my first assignment for my data structures course, so I'll be happy if you just show me where I am wrong instead of posting a working code.

We're supposed to write a program that given a degree sequence, draws a graph. I wrote the data structure for the graph, it can properly connect two vertices(graph.addConnection). But I couldn't be able to find a way to build a graph from a degree sequence.

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_sequence#Degree_sequence) gives a simple algorithm:

> 1. Begin with a graph with no edges.
> 2. Maintain a list of vertices whose degree requirement has not yet been met in non-increasing order of residual degree requirement.
> 3. Connect the first vertex to the next d1 vertices in this list, and then remove it from the list. Re-sort the list and repeat until all
>      degree requirements are met.

And I implemented it in Java like this:

```java
public static void populate(Graph graph, int[] degrees) {
    class DegreeMapping {
        int vertice=0;
        int degree=0;
    }

    ArrayList<DegreeMapping> degrees_ = new ArrayList<DegreeMapping>(degrees.length);
    for(int i=0; i<degrees.length; i++) {
        degrees_.add(new DegreeMapping());
        degrees_.get(i).vertice = i;
        degrees_.get(i).degree = degrees[i];
    }

    while(! degrees_.isEmpty()) {
        // Sort by degrees
        Collections.sort(degrees_, new Comparator<DegreeMapping>() {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(DegreeMapping o1, DegreeMapping o2) {
                                    return o2.degree - o1.degree ;
                                }
                            }); 
        for(DegreeMapping i: degrees_) System.out.printf("{%d, #%d} ", i.degree, i.vertice );
        System.out.println();

        for(int i=1; i<degrees_.get(0).degree+1; i++) {
            degrees_.get(i).degree--;
            graph.addConnection(degrees_.get(0).vertice, degrees_.get(i).vertice);
            System.out.printf("#%d <-> #%d \n", degrees_.get(0).vertice, degrees_.get(i).vertice);
        }

        degrees_.remove(0); 
    }
}
```

It gives this output for the degree sequence `2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2`:

```
{2, #0} {2, #1} {2, #2} {2, #3} {2, #4} {2, #5} {2, #6} {2, #7} 
#0 <-> #1 
#0 <-> #2 
{2, #3} {2, #4} {2, #5} {2, #6} {2, #7} {1, #1} {1, #2} 
#3 <-> #4 
#3 <-> #5 
{2, #6} {2, #7} {1, #4} {1, #5} {1, #1} {1, #2} 
#6 <-> #7 
#6 <-> #4 
{1, #7} {1, #5} {1, #1} {1, #2} {0, #4} 
#7 <-> #5 
{1, #1} {1, #2} {0, #5} {0, #4} 
#1 <-> #2 
{0, #2} {0, #5} {0, #4} 
{0, #5} {0, #4} 
{0, #4}
```

As you can see, it created two distinct groups with vertices {0, 1, 2} and {3, 4, 5, 6, 7} , there isn't any connection between them. But it supposed to create just one graph.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, that algorithm yields a simple graph, which, again according to Wikipedia, is 'an undirected graph that has no loops and no more than one edge between any two different vertices'.

What you get is a graph with two different connected components, not two graphs, so the algorithm seems to be working correctly.

If your assignment does not explicitly state that the graph should be connected, you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Sadly, my assignment states it. So, should I change the whole algorithm? Can you suggest anything?

Comment: Maybe you can just consider a path that joins all of the vertices together, subtract 1 from every element in the degree sequence, and then proceed with the algorithm.

Comment: But isn't there a possibility that; if I join all the vertices without the right order, the rest of them won't form a graph?

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, when you go through the graph you should not consider the vertices that are already connected as candidates for edge addition.

Comment: What do you mean by "without the right order"? If you iterate through the vertices adding an edge between the current one and the next, you'll have a path that involves all the vertices. I don't think there's an order to be considered, other than the one in which you have performed that operation, which is artificial.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work better if you also sort on the vertex-number.

```
// Sort by degrees and then vertex number
Collections.sort(degrees_, new Comparator<DegreeMapping>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(DegreeMapping o1, DegreeMapping o2) {
        if (o1.degree == o2.degree) return o2.vertice - o1.vertice;
        return o2.degree - o1.degree;
    }
});
```

**Result:**

```
{2, #0}, {2, #1}, {2, #2}, {2, #3}, {2, #4}, {2, #5}, {2, #6}, {2, #7}
#0 <-> #1
#0 <-> #2
{2, #3}, {2, #4}, {2, #5}, {2, #6}, {2, #7}, {1, #1}, {1, #2}
#3 <-> #4
#3 <-> #5
{2, #6}, {2, #7}, {1, #1}, {1, #2}, {1, #4}, {1, #5}
#6 <-> #7
#6 <-> #1
{1, #2}, {1, #4}, {1, #5}, {1, #7}, {0, #1}
#2 <-> #4
{1, #5}, {1, #7}, {0, #1}, {0, #4}
#5 <-> #7
{0, #7}, {0, #1}, {0, #4}
{0, #1}, {0, #4}
{0, #4}
```

---

According to the paper ["On Generating Graphs with Prescribed Degree Sequences for Complex Network Modeling Applications"](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~mihail/www-papers/aracne02.pdf) by Mihail and Vishnoi, you can create a connected graph by modifying the result of the algorithm afterwards.

> If this graph turns out to be unconnected, then one of the connected components must contain a cycle. Let (*u*, *v*) be any edge in a cycle and let (*s*, *t*) be an edge in a different connected component. Clearly, the graph does not have edges between the pairs *u*, *s* and *v*, *t*. By removing the edges (*u*, *v*) and (*s*, *t*), and inserting the edges (*u*, *s*) and (*v*, *t*), we merge these two components. Note that the resulting graph still satisfies the given degree sequence. Proceeding in this manner, we can get a connected topology.

Comment: It fixes that particular input, but it still fails, for example: `3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1`